# How to set unique queue name for ActiveMQ in MassTransit?

Tags: activemq-classic, masstransit

In `StartUp` of the project, I make the following settings for `MassTransit.ActiveMQ`. But when I run, it creates two queues for me, one is `event-listener` and the other is called `Generation`.

When I publish information, the information goes into the queues generated by the system.

But I want the information to be published inside queue `event-listener` that I set.

Please guide me

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<EventConsumer>();

    x.UsingActiveMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("localhost", h =>
        {  
            h.Username("admin");
            h.Password("admin");
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("event-listener", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<EventConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MassTransit will only create queues for configured consumers, or explicitly configured receive endpoints. In the code above, the only queue created would be called `event-listener`. For each message type consumed by the consumer, a topic is created and a virtual topic consumer is created so that the receive endpoint can consume messages of each type.

When messages are published, a *topic* is created for each published message type.

If you want to *send* a message directly to a queue, instead of publishing:

```cs
var provider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISendEndpointProvider>();

var endpoint = await provider.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:event-listener"));

await endpoint.Send(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.
How do I make settings so that it is not created  a virtual topic consumer?

Comment: `ConfigureConsumeTopology = false` should do it.

Comment: thank you. But when I tried this, it did not work, When I publish the message, it does not go into event-listener

Comment: Well, obviously not since you opted out of virtual topics/consumers by setting `ConfigureConsumeTopology = false`. You can't have pub/sub without topics/virtual consumers.